# Windows In Box / Hello Credential Provider api

Tags: windows, credential-providers, winlogon

Hi I know about the normal Credential Provider api, but is there an api for the Hello type providers?
Eg:

1. Windows Hello Face
2. Windows Hello Fingerprint
3. Windows Hello PIN
4. Picture Password

How does someone create a provider like that?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look carefully how they do enrolment - initially they ask you for your existing credentials. Later after verifying PIN (or smth else) push out saved credentials.

Comment: I think I get how they work in the background, but how do you create one?  does it impl ICredentialProvider?  if not, how does logonui know how to load / display it?

Comment: `Windows Hello` is back-end UI to control behaviour of this 4 CP's. When you enrols one of the Hello's method of logon the corresponding CP starts to enumerating one tile with **your account name** - this is designed as implementation of Credential Providers V2.

Comment: Winlogon every time present a list of available users and asks all of CP's "How many tiles do yo have to enumerate **NOW**?". Every CP report the number and later the tiles. Every tile is then asked "what is your account **SID**?" If the sid is compared with one of accounts the tile image of this CP is arranged under accounts name.